# Android porting - Status Bar customization

Tags: android, porting, statusbar

Hi I am trying to modify the statusbar icon in android. The file, statusbar_background.9.png is to modified. 
1. But could some one suggest me how to make it transparent? 
As for the customization, can we resize status bar width to a relative size? means,based on number of icons present on the screen?
I am modifying the file /frameworks/base/packages/systemui/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/statusbarservice.java

Please give me some suggestion
Thanks
Ab

Comment: your question is not clear can u paste your xml file and clearfy your question, i think u should use scrollview

Comment: Hi I am referring to android's source code. Also the xml file is status_bar.xml (presented in /frameworks/base/packages/systemui/res/layout/) folder.
In my understanding, the function used in StatusbarManager.java, is makestatusbarview(). where we need to specify it to be transparent?

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found the answer for my question.
I changed the following:
`android:background="@drawable/statusbar_background"`
to

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

inside the   `/framework/base/packages/systemui/res/statusbar.xml` file.

For resizing the status bar need to do the following: 
modify the `protected void addStatusBarView()` function in `StatusbarService.java` file with the following:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                //abhi 17 mar ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                mwidth, //specify the width of statusbar.. 
                height,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_STATUS_BAR,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TOUCHABLE_WHEN_WAKING,

                PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT
                );
        // abhi 15 march lp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL;
        lp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
        lp.setTitle("StatusBar");
        //lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;//abhi 18 march
        lp.windowAnimations = com.android.internal.R.style.Animation_StatusBar;
        lp.x = 25; // to move status bar to x position
        WindowManagerImpl.getDefault().addView(view, lp);

.....
}
```

Comment: What permission did you specify in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @dcanh121 - you don't, as you can't do this from a 3rd party app.  What is being discussed is a modification of the source code of Android itself.