# Get status bar color

Tags: android

I'm trying to show an overlay using window manager. I'd like to use the same background color currently used when the overlay is shown. Is it possible to get the current color of the status bar?

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739927/how-can-i-check-the-status-bar-colour-in-android

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.
Using [Window](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html)'s [getStatusBarColor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#getStatusBarColor%28%29) , you can able to get status bar color.